# does mySQL have native support for network programming?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, odbc

Does MySQL have native support for interacting with the internet, such as through REST APIs, etc.? I'm trying to figure out if I can pull data from the internet within an SQL script or I should figure out how to use an ODBC instead and connect it to a java app or something.

Comment: You can expose your MySQL server online, but it won't be an API. The remote client will directly connect to the database. Have a look at this: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL itself, out of the box, has no such support. It's a data store, not an application development framework.

If you're using Java in conjunction with MySQL then you can get Java to do the heavy lifting and persist the results in your database.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find a definitive answer anywhere. I will do that.